# Sql getting MAX and MIN values based on two columns for the ids from two others

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm having difficulties figuring a query out, would someone be able to assist me with this?
Problem: 4 columns that represent results for the 2 separate tests. One of them taken in UK and another in US. Both of them are the same test and I need to find the highest and lowest score for the test taken in both countries. I also need to avoid using subqueries and temporary tables. Would appreciate theoretical ideas and actual solutions for the problem.

The table looks like this:

```
 ResultID   Test_UK   Test_US   Test_UK_Score   Test_US_Score
   1          1         2       48              11
   2          4         1       21              24
   3          3         1       55              71
   4          5         6       18              78
   5          7         4       19              49
   6          1         3       23              69
   7          5         2       98              35
   8          6         7       41              47
```

The desired results I'm looking for:

```
TestID  HighestScore  LowestScore
   1       71             23
   2       35             11
   3       69             55
   4       49             21
   5       98             18
   6       78             41
   7       47             19
```

I tried implementing a case of comparison, but I still ended up with subquery to pull out the final results. Also tried union, but it ends up in a sub query again. As far as I can think it shoul be a case when then query, but can't really come up with the logic for it, as it requires to match the ID's of the tests.
Thank you!
What I've tried and got the best results (still wrong)

```
select v.TestID,
    max(case when Test_US_Score > Test_UK_Score then Test_UK_Score else null end) MaxS, 
    min(case when Test_UK_Score > Test_US_Score then Test_US_Score else null end) MinS
FROM ResultsDB rDB CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (Test_UK, 1), (Test_US, 0)
    ) V(testID, amount)
GROUP BY v.TestID
```

**Extra**

The answer provided by *M. Kanarkowski* is a perfect solution. I'm no expert on CTE, and a bit confused,  how would it be possible to adapt this query to return the result ID of the row that min and max were found.

something like this:

```
TestID Result_ID_Max Result_ID_Min
  1          3              6
  2          7              1 
  3          6              3
```

**Extra 2**

The desired results of the query would me something like this.
The two last columns represent the IDs of the rows from the original table where the max and min values were found.

```
TestID HighestScore LowestScore Result_ID_Of_Max Result_ID_Of_Min
  1         71           23            3              6
  2         35           11            7              1 
  3         69           55            6              3
```

Comment: "need to avoid ..." Why? Explain.

Comment: @SMor its one of the requirements, mainly performance

Comment: Test ID #2 has no UK results. Shouldn't it be excluded from your expected results? Also, 5 has no US results...

Comment: @EricBrandt no they shouldn't. The test not necessarily will be taken in both countries, and the same test can be taken in multiple locations in the same country, but I'm still looking for the max result of that particular test even if it was taken twice or more in the same country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can use `union` to have results from both countries togehter and then just pick the maximum and the minimum for your data.

```
with cte as (
    select Test_UK as TestID, Test_UK_Score as score from yourTable
    union all 
    select Test_US as TestID, Test_US_Score as score from yourTable
)
select
    TestID
    ,max(score) as HighestScore
    ,min(score) as LowestScore
from cte
group by TestID
order by TestID
```

Extra:
I assumed that you want to have the additional column with the previous result. If not just take the above select and replace `Test_UK_Score` and `Test_US_Score` with `ResultID`.

```
with cte as (
    select Test_UK as TestID, Test_UK_Score as score, ResultID from yourTable
    union all 
    select Test_US as TestID, Test_US_Score as score, ResultID from yourTable
)
select
    TestID
    ,max(score) as HighestScore
    ,min(score) as LowestScore
    ,max(ResultID) as Result_ID_Max
    ,min(ResultID) as Result_ID_Min
from cte
group by TestID
order by TestID
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. My question would be how would it be possible to adapt this query to return the result ID of the row that min and max were found.

something like this: 

`TestID  Result_ID_Max Result_ID_Min | 
    1               3                       6          |
    2               7                       1          |
    3               6                       3          |`

My apologies, I'm no expert with common table expressions, haven't considered the possibilities.

Comment: I added one more select to my post.

Comment: It is probably my way explaining, but that not exactly what I need.
I don't need the Max & Min of ResultID's. What I'm looking for is to have an extra column with the row ID (ResultID) of the rows from the table of where the max and min value was found. 
So let's say if a result with ID 1 had max value for Test ID 1 and result with ID 2 had the min value for Test ID 1 I would have two extra columns saying that max value if from Result ID 1 and the min value is from Result ID 2 for the Test1 
Adding this to the original post now for better explanation